# How to get rid of VS 2015 update 2?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, intellisense

I made the mistake to apply this update 2, which makes the already bad intellisense totally slow and unusable (at least on my computer with c++ projects). Latter I found out this is probably caused by the new SQL database.  I tried to:

- just uninstall the update - VS 2015 doesn't start any more
- delete the registry - worked the first start, with some icons missing, then stopped working again
- install update 1 again - not possible, it starts update 2
- uninstall completely and use the vs2015.1 iso - it detects update 2 and tries to install it
- disconnect from internet - the installer just crashes...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you look at the system restore points?

Comment: I'm afraid of using yet another flawed MS technology... I think I keep the restore point, but even the text there doesn't inspire confidence - "programs and drivers that *might* be restored"...

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Uninstaller
This executable is designed to cleanup/scorch all Preview/RC/RTM releases of Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio vNext. It should be used as the last resort to clean up the user's system before resorting to reimaging the machine.

Running this application will break Visual Studio 2012 and earlier versions of Visual Studio because Visual Studio 2012 have some MSIs that have the same upgrade codes as Visual Studio 2013 and above.

Download: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases

Answer (score 0):

Forcibly uninstall using original installer
You do not need to have a bundle installed to forcibly uninstall packages by default. If you have the original installer – say, a previous download – you can run it directly like so:

vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force

Details available at - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall/